# In MySQL, how to extract an URL from a long text string?

Tags: mysql, string, wordpress, phpmyadmin, substring

I'm learning MySQL and using phpMyAdmin to make changes in my Wordpress database for a store with thousands of products.

I'm trying to do a quick update where I pull out an URL and paste it into a shortcode I want to add.

Currently, each record in my table has this somewhere within a bunch of other text.

```
<input type="hidden" name="prtks" value="http://domainname/folder/filename.mp3"/>
```

I want to keep this and add to each record within the same field

```
[sc_embed_player_template1 fileurl="url from above"/"]
```

It's rather tricky as I know I can find a substring by counting the characters, but is there a way to pull out the full URL from http all the way to the final .mp3?

thanks much!

Comment: Just use the search and replace plugin to make the changes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't in MySQL, but if I understand your question correctly, you seem like you're talking about doing this within a php file by doing something like the following:

```
<?php 
    $url = '<input type="hidden" name="prtks" value="http://domainname/folder/filename.mp3"/>';
    $parts = explode('"', $url);
    echo 'URL: '.$parts[5];
?>
```

This uses php `explode()` to break the string into an array based on " characters.

You can then just echo the 6th part (`$parts[5]`)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a simple regex to extract the url ?

```
$str = '<input type="hidden" name="prtks" value="http://domainname/folder/filename.mp3"/>';
preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', $str, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($match[0][0]);
// string 'http://domainname/folder/filename.mp3' (length=37)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function urltxt($string)
{

$regex = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i"; ///(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
  return $matches[0];
}

$url = urltxt($sqlresult);
echo $url[0];

//this way its more easier i guess
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file extensions are all 3 chars, you could use a regular expression like `http://*\.{3}` to find the URL, but unless they have some sort of delimiter, it would be hard to find. you could try `http://*\.(mp3|html|gif|png|exe|php|aif|wav)` and list all possible extensions if they're different. You could also try only listing extensions that have more than 3 chars: `http://*\.({3}|html|jpeg|aiff|torrent)`.